# How can I display a decimal number so that the integer part appears larger text size and the decimal part smaller

Tags: php, format, numbers

How can I display a decimal number so that the integer part appears larger text size and the decimal part smaller

I am working with smarty templates (php), I get a variable that already has the total price included, example "75.45 €" and I would like to highlight the integer part of a decimal number so that it appears larger and the decimal part smaller, to turn also has the euro symbol included in the string.

I put an example:

[image]

***EDIT***

Thanks to ProtoN is solved:

```
      {$string = '75,45 €'}
      {assign var="parts" value="."|explode:$string}
      {if $string|strstr:","}
      <span style="font-size: 1.5rem;color:red">{$parts[0]}</span>,<span>{$parts[1]}</span>
      {else}
      <span style="font-size: 1.5rem;color:green;">{$parts[0]}</span><span>{$parts[1]}</span>
      {/if}
```

Comment: In 2 different `<span>` with different css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode the variable and just use basic HTML/CSS to style the different span's..

something like that

```
$string = '75.45 €';
    echo '<span style="font-size: 1.5rem;">' . explode('.', $string)[0] . '.</span><span>' . explode('.', $string)[1] . '</span>';
```

Comment: It works correctly in php but in the smarty templates I can't add the code as is. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylar i guess it will be something like this `<span style="font-size:2rem;">{","|explode:$string[0]}</span>` you just need to figure out the Smarty way to insert functions into your HTML. otherwise, do it on your Controller/Model